# Calculate Case Age in days excluding weekends and holidays, always adding 1 day to the result

Tags: apex, formula, case

I have a trigger and a utility class where I'm trying to calculate case age, excluding weekends and Holidays, and adding 1 day to the final result. I am not getting the result I expect and am looking for some assistance with my code. I'll preface with I am an Admin, so not proficient in Apex.

Here is the trigger:

```
trigger CalculateCaseAge on Case (before insert, before update) {
    // Retrieve the list of holidays
    List<Holiday> holidays = [SELECT ActivityDate FROM Holiday];

    // Calculate Case age
    for (Case c : Trigger.new) {
        if (c.CreatedDate != null) {
            Boolean isClosed = c.Status == 'Closed'; // Check if the case is closed
            // Calculate the number of business days between case creation date and now
            Decimal businessDays = BusinessDaysCalculator.calculateBusinessDays(c.CreatedDate, System.now(), holidays, isClosed);
            
            // Add 1 day to the final result
            c.Age__c = businessDays + 1.0;
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the utility class:

```
public class BusinessDaysCalculator {
    public static Decimal calculateBusinessDays(DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate, List<Holiday> holidays, Boolean isClosed) {
        Integer businessDays = 0;
        while (startDate <= endDate) {
            if (isClosed) {
                break;
            }
            if (!isWeekend(startDate) && !containsHoliday(startDate, holidays)) {
                businessDays++;
            }
            startDate = startDate.addDays(1);
        }
        return Decimal.valueOf(businessDays);
    }
    
    private static Boolean isWeekend(DateTime dt) {
        // Use DateTime class to get day of the week
        String dayOfWeek = dt.format('u');
        return dayOfWeek == '6' || dayOfWeek == '7'; // '6' is Saturday, '7' is Sunday
    }
    
    private static Boolean containsHoliday(DateTime dt, List<Holiday> holidays) {
        for (Holiday h : holidays) {
            if (h.ActivityDate == dt.date()) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Laura, welcome to SFSE! It seems like you'd benefit from some basic understanding of triggers/classes as well as execution contexts. Salesforce has a lot of good content to get you started with Apex on Trailhead, and I can also recommend sfdc99.com as a good resource to get started.

The code you posted above is incomplete, there's no way to tell from this snippet whether or not the `days` variable is ever being set on a Case, or what context this code is running in (before/after insert/update, etc). Is this existing code in your system or code you found online?

Comment: Hi, and thank you for the resources! I am an Admin, so I definitely have a very limited understanding of apex. I am looking to learn and get some help on my requirement. I have a formula field that is working great to calculate Case Age excluding weekends and adding 1 day to the result; my issue is excluding Holidays as well. I added all the Holidays in the Holiday object in Salesforce, but I can't seem to use that in a formula. I found this code online and am trying to use it, but am stuck. Any help is greatly appreciated.